# Gitlab CI reference file from another project in a kubectl command

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl

I have a gitlab CI pipeline that is running this command:

```
kubectl apply -f my-kube.yaml
```

I would like to move `my-kube.yaml` to a common place instead of having it in every project.  I already include a common pipeline using

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'somepath/somepath/someProject'
    file: 'someFile.yml'
```

Can i do this for a file like `my-kube.yaml` too?

Comment: Let me know if my answer below addresses your concerns or if you had something else in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to resolve the issue was this:

```
- 'wget --header="PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MY_TOKEN" -O my-kube.yaml https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/001/repository/files/my-kube-001.yaml/raw?ref=master'
- kubectl apply -f my-kube.yaml
```

Note you could also use curl instead of wget